# How to loop a script execution with param from a text file?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell-script

I need to run ./pythonScript keyword one time for each keyword in a text file, how can I do this from a gnome terminal? (without having to modify the pythonScript)

pseudo code:

```
for each keyword in file:
  ./pythonScript keyword
  waitfor(pythonScript to finish)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is one keyword per line, here's a pure shell, portable solution:

```
while read -r line; do
    ./pythonScript "$line"
done <file
```

Here's a slightly simpler Linux solution:

```
<file xargs -d '\n' -n 1 ./pythonScript
```

Both solutions allow any character other than newline to appear in a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a keyword per line from the file?  If so,

```
while read keyword
do
    ./pythonScript $keyword
done < file
```

Comment: Yes the keywords are one per line (but some are phrases like "keyw1 and keyw2" in the same line), Would it still work?

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel http:// www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ installed you can do this:

```
cat file | parallel ./pythonScript
```

This will run the jobs in parallel can be very useful if you run on a multicore machine.

Watch the intro video for GNU Parallel to learn more:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ